# synchronize gnome 3 (panel) settings between computers

Tags: gnome3, gnome-panel, dconf, gsettings, gnome-classic

I'd like to synchronize the configuration of my gnome panel(s) between computers and keep the configuration in Git. How can I dump / import the necessary information? I already found `gconftool2 --dump` but did not find anything that looked like my panel configuration inside.

**Update:** I'm using gnome3 classic mode (together with xmonad as window-manager). I found the configuration setting with the dconf-editor below org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout. It's however still cumbersome to come up with the correct shell scripting to extract and sync only the configuration that I want to share.

I've opened a wishlist issue in the gnome bugzilla for a dconf sync tool: [710930](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710930)

Answer (score 7):

**Updated answer**

With dconf (which you are using), gnome-panel's config can be dumped out with the following command:

`dconf dump /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout > settings.txt`

Then you can edit the file (it's plain text file) to contain only the settings you want to sync, and then load the settings from the file as following:

`dconf load /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout < settings.txt`

**Original answer**

I think `gconftool` should work well. The following command will dump gnome-panels settings (from directory `~/.gconf/apps/panel`) to .xml file called `backup.xml`: `gconftool --dump /apps/panel > backup.xml`.

Then do the following to load configs from `backup.xml`: `gconftool --load backup.xml`.

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that I'm asking about the classic mode panel. Please see my update.

Comment: How can I dump ALL dconf settings and sycn them to another machine? Is it safe to do so?